# Error: Can't find variable: WindowsAzure

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile services with ionic and I'm trying to create my client in a factory as a singleton. However when trying to use the client like I did normally I keep getting this error Error: Can't find variable: WindowsAzure. Thank you in advance.

Factory

```
.factory('client', [function(){
var myjsonObj = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://xxx.azurewebsites.net');
return myjsonObj;
}])
```

Controller where I call it

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'md5', 'Userid', '$state','$ionicSideMenuDelegate','$ionicLoading','client',// The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams,md5,Userid,$state,$ionicSideMenuDelegate,$ionicLoading,client) {

$scope.UserInfo = {};

$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);


  $scope.show = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: '<p>Loading...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'
    });
  };

  $scope.hide = function(){
        $ionicLoading.hide();
  };

$scope.login =function(){

$scope.show($ionicLoading);








    if ($scope.UserInfo.password == null){
        $scope.UserInfo.password = "fa";
    }




    var query = client.getTable('clubUser')
    .where({ Email: $scope.UserInfo.email, Password: md5.createHash($scope.UserInfo.password) })
    .read()
    .done(function(results) {


        if(results[0] == undefined)
        {

            $scope.errorText = "Error: Wrong Username/Password";
            $scope.$apply();
            $scope.hide($ionicLoading); 
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.hide($ionicLoading); 
            Userid.setJson(results[0].id);

            $state.go('tabsController.qRCode');

        }




    }, function(error) {

        console.dir(error);
        $scope.hide($ionicLoading); 
    });

$scope.UserInfo.password = "";




};



}])
```

Comment: It seems that script is not loaded. Are you using npm package or script?

Comment: I located my project in the cmd and used cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps to install. @Volodymyr Bilyachat

Comment: Cordova plugin works only on mobile, and i assume you are running it in browser is that right?

Comment: I am actually only using mobile, I am testing on an iOS Device with Xcode @VolodymyrBilyachat

Comment: Try to do this var WindowsAzure = require('azure-mobile-apps-client'); before you create instance

Comment: I haven't used it but take a look here https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/blob/cordova-2.0.0/README.md

Comment: This gives me a different error of " Error: Can't find variable: require " @VolodymyrBilyachat thanks so much for the help btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after looking into the error and not finding any results I decided to add the mobile services plugin manually through adding the script in my index and now it works great! Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the app is in the "ready" state (i.e. all JavaScript libraries are loaded).  In Ionic, it's best to use a factory to ensure a singleton.  That will also assure you that it is loading at the right time.